# Logical Error While using Modulus % Operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been learning Ruby. And I've wrote a small program. I'm facing a logical error which I'm not able to fix so far. Here is the code.

```
 1:  puts 'Please enter the starting Year'  
 2:  startingYear = gets.chomp  
 3:  puts 'Please enter the ending Year'  
 4:  endingYear = gets.chomp  
 5:  while(startingYear.to_i <= endingYear.to_i)  
 6:     if(startingYear%4 == 0)
 7:            if((startingYear%400 == 0) or (startingYear%100 != 0))
 8:                   puts startingYear
 9:            end
10:     end
11:     startingYear = startingYear.to_i + 1
12:  end
```

Here is what this program does.
It asks for a starting year and an ending year, and then 'puts' all of the leap years between them (and including them, if they are also leap years). Leap years are years divisible by four (like 1984 and 2004). However, years divisible by 100 are not leap years (such as 1800 and 1900) unless they are divisible by 400 (like 1600 and 2000, which were in fact leap years).

I used Ruby debugger too. When I execute the program It simply skips line number 6 on its very first iteration. After that it works completely fine.
For example: When I use input 1600 for starting year and 2000 for the ending year. Then the output starts from:

1604,
1608,
1612,
.
.
.
.
.
1696,
1704,
1708,
.
.
.
.
.
.
1992,
1996,
2000
I mean logically it should show 1600 too but the program simply skips it. I know it is just a hair line like error. But I just can't able to figure it out.

P.S. I'm a newbie so please ignore any kind of stupid mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Convert your strings to integers once at the start:

```
startingYear = gets.chomp.to_i 
endingYear = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Then you don't have to use `to_i` anywhere else in your code.

Your program is skipping line 6 the first iteration because your `startingYear` is a string the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a string `"1600"` initially, to which the string formatting method `%` applies, and returns `self`. which is not `0`, so it does not satisfy the condition. From the second iteration, it is converted to an integer, so it works as you intended. You should convert the string once directly after the input:

```
startingYear = gets.to_i
endingYear = gets.to_i
```

Also, note some redundancy in your logic. For example, if a year is divisible by 400, then it follows that it is divisible by 4, so nesting the test for the former inside the test for the latter is redundant. A cleaner logic would be like this:

```
(startingYear..endingYear).each do |year|  
  if    (year % 400).zero? then puts year
  elsif (year % 100).zero?
  elsif (year %   4).zero? then puts year
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This piece of advice is another gem for me. Will keep this in mind next time. :)